# C# Single Pipe Syntax

Tags: c#

```
var schedule = builder
    .OnDaysOfWeek(DayInterval.Mon | DayInterval.Wed | DayInterval.Fri)
    .HavingFrequency(FrequencyType.Weekly)
    .Create();
```

http://schedulewidget.azurewebsites.net/

What is the `|` syntax here, and more importantly how do I loop through a list of days and generate a varialbe to pass to: `.HavingFrequence(myMagicVarHere)`.

I need something like:
`var myMagicVar = DayInterval.Mon | DayInterval.Wed | DayInterval.Fri`, obviously that doesn't work.

Edit: Peeking defineition: `public ScheduleBuilder HavingFrequency(FrequencyType type)`

Comment: "obviously that doesn't work." - why not? what does that say?

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh, sorry, I need to generate this list dynamically. I have a list of days, I need to build myMagicalVar from that.

Comment: so... `DayInterval days = DayInterval.None; if (monday) days |= DayInterval.Mon; if (tuesday) days |= DayInterval.Tue; ... ; SomeMethod(days);` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` is "or", in the arithmetic / bitwise sense. It is often used with `[Flags] enum` declarations  - i.e. if `Mon` is `1` and `Wed` is `4` and `Fri` is `16`, then `Mon | Wed | Fri` is `21`, which can be understood by code that knows how to check for `[Flags]`. Note that `|` *can* be used with more complex types, if custom operators are defined.

Comment: Thank you, I am also trying to pass it as a param.